# I have a formula that pulls four-digit numbers from a string in a cell--now I want it to pull the second instance, or multiple instances

Tags: excel, excel-formula

EDIT:  I should have said, that as good or better than outputting all four-digit numbers would be a count function that counts the number of four-digit uninterrupted numbers.

And, whether a number output or count, I need to pull the formula downwards across a couple thousand rows.   Thank you to everyone who replied so far, appreciate your help!

---

This formula finds the first four-digit number in a string--but I need to find either the second instance of a four-digit number, or the last, or generate all.   Just not the first one.   Useful formula in need of a tweak, thank you for your consideration:  `=MID(D2,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"0","-"),"1","-"),"2","-"),"3","-"),"4","-"),"5","-"),"6","-"),"7","-"),"8","-"),"9","-")),4)`

I already tried a formula adjusted from the top answer on this thread: [Excel: How to extract only the 6 digit number present in a cell string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935549/excel-how-to-extract-only-the-6-digit-number-present-in-a-cell-string)

For this text in a cell:  **"Test 1 military time 1982 2008 2009 203401"**

This formula:  `=MID(D2,FIND("----",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"0","-"),"1","-"),"2","-"),"3","-"),"4","-"),"5","-"),"6","-"),"7","-"),"8","-"),"9","-")),4)`

Generates this: **"1982"**

I would like it to output **2008**, or **1982,2008,2009,2034,** or just one of the results after the first one, **1982**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ways.

Since you say 2034 is acceptable, could you just look for the first `space` going from right to left, and then take the 4 next numbers? If that space rule will hold (then this is a nice short one that will return **2034**:

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2, " ",REPT("?", 999)), 999),"?",""),4)`

If you want the first 4 digit number after the first (As you described with **2008**):
   `=MID($D$2,FIND("!!!!!",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"0","-"),"1","-"),"2","-"),"3","-"),"4","-"),"5","-"),"6","-"),"7","-"),"8","-"),"9","-"),"----","!!!!!",2)),4)`

Or here's austom Function Using VBA:

```
Function fDigitOutup(xString As String) As String
Dim p As Long, foundFour As Boolean, ftext As String

ftext = Replace(xString, " ", "")


    p = 4
    Do While Len(fDigitOutup) < 4 And p < 5000

        If Not foundFour Then
            If IsNumeric(Mid(ftext, p - 3, 4)) Then
                foundFour = True
            End If
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Mid(ftext, p, 1)) Then
                fDigitOutup = fDigitOutup & Mid(ftext, p, 1)
            End If
        End If

        p = p + 1
    Loop


End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified in my example, these are text strings with lots of words and numbers irregularly spaced.   So the end of the line could easily have spaces that don't announce the beginning of the numbers I want to identify.

Your second solution worked though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In **D3** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"0","-"),"1","-"),"2","-"),"3","-"),"4","-"),"5","-"),"6","-"),"7","-"),"8","-"),"9","-")
```

in **D4** enter:

```
=MID($D$2,FIND("xxxx",SUBSTITUTE($D$3,"----","xxxx",ROWS($1:1))),4)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, this looks great!   I should have made it clear, that my dataset is a bunch of rows, so I need to get the result in a single cell with one formula preferrably, that I can drag down all 2,700 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since `2034` is an acceptable return value, if you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **Array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[number()>=1000]"),4))
```

If really just want values in the range `1000-9999`, then you can use this **Array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[number()>=1000 and number()<=9999]"))
```

Since the above are **array** formulas, you need to "confirm" them by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

[image]

If you don't have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can output the values 1 at a time by using the `INDEX` function.  For example, to output those values in separate cells in the adjoining columns:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()>=1000]"),4),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

and fill right as far as might be necessary:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I have Mac for Excel and that first formula didn't work off the bat, although it sounds awesome.    The 1 at a time method probably won't work as I'm trying to apply this extending the formula down a sheet of 2700 row entries.

Comment: @ecar Why shouldn't it work?  You can just fill across, and then fill down (or, vice versa).  Otherwise, you'll need a VBA solution.