# Excel question: How to find duplicate string of six digits in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm dealing with a spreadsheet containing ranges of Bates numbers for legal discovery. All numbers are six digits. A typical cell might be named something like "Court records 000001-000100" or "Search warrant 000300-000300." Is there are way to identify cells where the SAME six-digit string is repeated, as in the second example, and replace it with only the first instance of that string? E.g., "Search warrant 000300."

I prefer a formula, but VBA would also work. I've found methods for identifying ANY six-digit string, but not one that will specifically look for the same number twice. Thank you so much for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: `I've found methods for identifying ANY six-digit string, but not one that will specifically look for the same number twice.` maybe you can share that, because that might be helpful for us helping you.

Comment: This was one suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935549/how-to-extract-the-six-digit-number-in-a-cell-string

This was another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493931/extract-fixed-length-number-from-excel-cell

However, I don't believe either of these would let me specify that I need the same number twice.

Comment: Which excel-version are you using?

Comment: Looks like Excel for Office 365.

Comment: Looking at the sample data, maybe just `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)-6,6),"")` may work?

Comment: It can be so easy. :)

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but unfortunately many file names are much more complex and contain a dash in the middle (E.g. "2016 tax records - Smith," "2016 tax records - Jones," etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With o365 you can use

```
=IF(LET(arr,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""),"_"," "),"-"," "),".pdf","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),AGGREGATE(15,6,arr/ISNUMBER(arr),1)=AGGREGATE(15,6,arr/ISNUMBER(arr),2)),LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1)&".pdf",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".pdf","")&".pdf")
```

For other versions one needs to replace every `arr` with the `FILTERXML`-part. If it is possible that there are other punctuation marks around the numbers, then these must also be substituted.
[image]

EDIT 1: Just read, that you want to delete the duplicate.

EDIT 2: This formula would keep the `.pdf`-file-extension.

EDIT 3: Preparing for `_` and `&`. This assumes, that already redacted documents never have duplicates numbers, as they are already redacted.

Comment: Should the formula keep the `.pdf`-part?

Comment: Thank you! This works beautifully, except that I neglected to mention that the file names end in a ".pdf." Mea culpa! This appears to create an issue with stripping out the period in the file suffix and making it difficult for the formula to recognize the duplicate. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much - you have no idea how much of a timesaver this will be!

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark as answer if you are satisfied. Have a nice day or evening as it is in my case. :)

Comment: I will! 

I am running into one issue ... in a case where a file is already redacted, I am getting a #VALUE! or $NUM! error (probably because the file name in that case is something like "Business records 000200-000250_Redacted.pdf".  Is there a workaround for that?It also seems to generate sometimes when the file is NOT redacted but contains an ampersand -- for example "Letter & probate documents 000300-000310".

Comment: In the `FILTERXML`-part you can nest more `SUBSTITUTE`-functions like the three ones already in there for possible connecting-chars like the underscore and ampersand.

Comment: When I'm home later, I can extend the formula.

Comment: I tried that but I may have placed it in the wrong place. I have just enough Excel knowledge to be dangerous, lol.

Comment: Ok, i implemented the other things. But my formula should also fail for the cases you mentioned to JvdV, if there are duplicates for the numbers.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If not already in a table, turn it into a table using **Insert Table** from the data ribbon. This allows you to refer to other columns by name and store column formulas once per *column" rather than have to drag it down the column and store the formula once per cell.

Assuming your doc name column title is "DocName", add a column titled "JustNumbers" with a formula of `=RIGHT([@DocName],13)`

Then add another column with a formula of

```
`=IF(LEFT([@JustNumbers],6)=RIGHT([@JustNumbers],6), LEFT([@DocName],LEN([@DocName])-7),[@DocName])`
```

You can hide the other columns and just show this last column.

Comment: You should `SUBSTITUTE` a possible `.` for the formula to work for every case, like OPs two examples show.